# How to access model attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf, modelattribute

I need to pass a model attribute from controller to HTML. My application is using HTML5, thymeleaf & springboot.

I am using the below code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var modelAttributeValue = '${modelAttribute}';
}
```

Code snippet from my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("modelAttribute", "viewEmployee")
```

But I am not able to get the value assigned to model attribute in HTML.

Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to use an inline script, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    $(document).ready(function() {
       var modelAttributeValue = [[${modelAttribute}]];
    }

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

More info on script inlining here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion and added info on inline script. I'll try the solution.